# groupby query by year

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

`shipwynum` is the primary key for `convertship` table.

Actually this query getting data correct, for year 2008 only. When i replace 2008 with any other year then also getting data correct for that year. This query display the total records for that year not in `TotalCount`. `TotalCount` has always one becoz i have group by with `shipwynum`.
But i want to get data for 1000 to 2011 separately(instead a particular year like 2008)  in this one query and `TotalCount` should display the counts for every year.

I have this query :=

```
    select
    distinct
    count(con.shipwynum) as TotalCount,
    con.shipwynum,
    s.deldat,
    s.deldat as DeliveryQuarter,
    left(s.deldat,4) as DelYear
    from convertship con
    left join shipscheduled s on con.shipwynum = s.shipwynum and s.deleted = 'N'
    where left(s.deldat,4) > 1000 and left(s.deldat,4) <= 2008 and
    left(con.condat,4) > 2008 and
    con.deleted = 'N' and
    con.wytypid in ('66', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17','18') and
    s.wytypid not in ('66', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17','18')
    group by con.shipwynum
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to count number of rows for each year?

From what i assume,
there is one main table `convertship` and you want to join `convertship` to `shipscheduled`.
Then do the group by on that data according to its `left(con.condat,4)` value.

```
select distinct     
  count(con.shipwynum) as TotalCount,     
  con.shipwynum,     
  s.deldat,     
  s.deldat as DeliveryQuarter,     
  left(s.deldat,4) as DelYear,   
  left(con.condat,4) as ConYear
from
  convertship con     
inner join 
  shipscheduled s on con.shipwynum = s.shipwynum  
where 
  left(s.deldat,4) > 1000 and 
  left(s.deldat,4) <= 2008 and     
  -- left(con.condat,4) > 2008 and     
  con.deleted = 'N' and     
  s.deleted = 'N' and
  con.wytypid in ('66','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18') and    
  s.wytypid not in ('66','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18')     
group by 
  left(con.condat,4)
```

I assume the `convertship` table is not too big, if not this will not work.

Comment: Since its mysql why use LEFT when YEAR may suit better

Comment: and the `left join` is actually cancelled by the `where` conditions. You could replace it with `inner join`.

Comment: when i remove your comment and replace with   `left(s.deldat,4) > 1000 and 
  left(s.deldat,4) <= 2002 and     
  left(con.condat,4) > 2002 and` then its getting 6 records for year 2002. But in your query there is only 1 TotalCounts for ConYear 2002. ?

Comment: @AdrianCornish i am not sure if the value is of type date or varchar

Comment: @ypercube i agree, much more logical

Comment: @J.J. i put an extra join condition

Comment: con.condat and s.deldat are varchar type.

Comment: @cctan Why you are joining with this `left(con.condat,4) = left(s.deldat,4)` condition

Comment: @cctan Although the docs don't say I would may the assumption that its an int http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Comment: @AdrianCornish some devs like to use string like 20081011 to store their date, i figure J.J. case is similar, nevermind then; its varchar.

Comment: @J.J. I thought you would want to join those 2 date, I was wrong, you wanted a kind of cross join. edited.

Comment: may be... :) By the way expecting some ideas or ans :)

Comment: @cctan Good point - I assumed that OP was using date/datetime cols - now I get the substr reference. With SQL's hidden conversions thought it can provide hidden delays

Comment: @J.J. what are you expecting? does the edited answer above work?

Comment: @cctan not working, getting 1 for 2002 and 2 for 2011. but should be 6 for 2002 and 2 for 2008, as increasing the year the counts go down.

Comment: @J.J. Hmm, is there a sample of the data? Its hard to see the patterns with column names only

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select  count(con.shipwynum) as TotalCount,
        con.shipwynum,
        s.deldat,
        s.deldat as DeliveryQuarter,
        left(s.deldat,4) as DelYear
from convertship con
left join shipscheduled s 
       on con.shipwynum = s.shipwynum and 
          s.deleted = 'N' and
          left(s.deldat,4) > 1000 and 
          left(s.deldat,4) < left(con.condat,4) and
          s.wytypid not in ('66', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17','18')
where   con.deleted = 'N' and
        con.wytypid in ('66', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17','18') and
group by con.shipwynum, left(s.deldat,4)
```

Note that since deldat and DeliveryQuarter are neither grouped by nor aggregated, their values in the output will essentially be random (within the DelYear).